# Sending slack message in jenkins with ${currentBuild.number}

Tags: jenkins, slack, jenkins-slack-plugins

Hey i've been trying to send message with my number of build in a slack message in my jenkins pipeline using slacksend like this

```
 slackSend channel: 'developer-team', message: 'The unit tests have been successful for Build N°: ${currentBuild.number}'
```

but the message i get from slack is this way :

> The unit tests have been successful for Build N°:  ${currentBuild.number}

i don't know how to fix to get the appropriate message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```yaml
slackSend channel: '#notification', color: 'good', message: "The unit tests have been successful for Build N°: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", teamDomain: 'testnotifgroup', tokenCredentialId: 'slack-token'
```

> Use double quotes " " to wrap your message